# Can't get GET to work when POST works perfectly

Tags: c#, jquery, .net-3.5, asmx

I have the following code, which works perfectly if I use `POST`.  However, I need to get it to work with `GET` for various reasons:  (I've added comments to show the 3 simple changes I made, see CHANGE 1 and CHANGE 2 in the client-side script, and CHANGE 3 in the server-side script):

**Client-side:**

```
function selectedDateTime(strDate, strHours, strMinutes) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'webservice.asmx/GetCount',
        //type: 'POST', // CHANGE 1 - THIS WAS POST
        type: 'GET',
        //data: '{"theDate": "' + strDate + ' ' + strHours + ':' + strMinutes + ':00"}', // CHANGE 2 - REMOVED THE CURLY BRACKETS
        data: '"theDate": "' + strDate + ' ' + strHours + ':' + strMinutes + ':00"',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function(department) {
            console.log("success: " + department.d); 
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("status message: " + status);
            console.log("error message: " + error);
            console.log("xhr message: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

}
```

**Server-side:**

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] // CHANGE 3 - ADDED THIS LINE TO FORCE A GET
public double GetCount(string theDate)
{
    string[] strDateAndTime = theDate.Split(' ');

    string[] strStartDateParts = strDateAndTime[0].Split('/');
    string[] srtStartTimeParts = strDateAndTime[1].Split(':');

    int year = Int32.Parse(strStartDateParts[2]);
    int month = Int32.Parse(strStartDateParts[1]);
    int day = Int32.Parse(strStartDateParts[0]);
    int hour = Int32.Parse(srtStartTimeParts[0]);
    int min = Int32.Parse(srtStartTimeParts[1]);
    int sec = Int32.Parse(srtStartTimeParts[2]);

    DateTime meetingDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
    {

        using (command = new SqlCommand("intranet.dbo.BusinessHours", connection))
        {

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@meeting_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = meetingDate;

            connection.Open();

            using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                return (double)reader["hours"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error message:**

I used Google Chrome's developer tools to extract this error message.

```
GET http://intranet/webservice.asmx/GetCount?%22theDate%22:%20%2201/07/2013%2013:00:00%22 500 (Internal Server Error) 
status message: error 
error message: Internal Server Error 
xhr message: {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027theDate\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

**Question:**

Anyone know why this is happening, when it works perfectly using `POST`.  I just want to do the same thing, but need to use `GET` instead.

Comment: add data in query string while making get request

Comment: The query string does have data doesn't it? Please see the first line of the error message.

Comment: you are trying to pass json object in query string...server ll' not able to understand request with that format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date =  '"' +strDate + ' ' + strHours + ':' + strMinutes + ':00"';
$.ajax({
        url: 'webservice.asmx/GetCount?theDate=date,
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function(department) {
            console.log("success: " + department.d); 
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("status message: " + status);
            console.log("error message: " + error);
            console.log("xhr message: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Based on this, I am getting the following error message: `GET http://intranet/webservice.asmx/GetCount?theDate=01/07/2013%2013:00:00%22 500 (Internal Server Error)` and `xhr message: {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: 07/2013 13:00:00\".",`

Comment: Got it working, it should have been `var date =  '"' + strDate + ' ' + strHours + ':' + strMinutes + ':00"';`, thank.s

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing JSON as query string. It works in POST but not in GET.
for GET you need

```
 data: 'theDate=' + strDate + ' ' + strHours + ':' + strMinutes + ':00'
```

Comment: Hello, I've updated my question based on this, as the error continues even after making this change.  Please see the updated question.